# how do I install Vuze 5.2?

Tags: installation, updates, software-recommendation, versions, vuze

Currently Vuze 4.3.0.6 is installed from `apt-get`.

I want to update to the latest Vuze version.  Can I download a JAR?  I hesitate to manually install software.

[image]

current version is 5.2 on vuze.com -- quite a leap.

If I install from the website, what impact will this have on the system?  I would rather use `apt-get` to install software.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't cause any damages to your system,if you install it from website.

Download *Vuze 5.2* from [*here*](http://www.vuze.com/download.php).

Comment: ok, this seems to work.  I don't think that the Vuze download actually "installs" anything to the system, it just seems to run a JAR -- which is what I wanted.  However, how do you **know** that it doesn't effect, or change, or damage the system to install this manually, so that down the road other things break?

Comment: the download link was an official one,so it doesn't cause any damages.